# DateTime Conversion Could not be completed because of Kind Mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to convert local time to UTC:

The Kind for earliestStartTime.Value.Kind = Local.

How will I convert local to UTC

```
TimeZoneInfo tmz =   
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneValue.Value.ToString());

 earliestStartTime = 
        TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(earliestStartTime.Value, tmz, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

Comment: Is the data stored in a DateTime object? Then check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
```

`var kind = convertedDate.Kind;` // will equal DateTimeKind.Unspecified
You say you know what kind it is, so tell it.

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
    DateTime.Parse(dateStr),
    DateTimeKind.Utc);

var kind = convertedDate.Kind; // will equal DateTimeKind.Utc
```

Now, once the system knows its in UTC time, you can just call ToLocalTime:

```
DateTime dt = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
```